# Use Eloquent to get information from a foreign key, when that foreign key has multiple columns in the table

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4.2 and have a table called *users* and a column in that table labeled **name**. I also have a transactions table that has 2 columns which are both foreign keys that reference the primary key of the *users* table. One of the rows in the *transactions* is labeled *given_to* and the other is labeled *received_from*. **How can I access the name associated with the given_to user id from the transactions table using Eloquent?** I tried the following in a view and received a *trying to get property of non-object error*:

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
    {{ $transaction->given_to->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly map the relationship between the objects and alias them.
Like

```
class Transactions extends Eloquent
{
  public function givenTo()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Users', 'given_to');
  }
  public function receivedFrom()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Users', 'received_from');
  }
}
class Users extends Eloquent
{
  public function outgoingTransactions()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Transactions', 'given_to');
  }
  public function incomingTransactions()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Transactions', 'received_from');
  }
}
```

then use the aliased functions in your view.

Comment: but when I do something like this
{{ $transaction->given_to->givenTransaction() }} in the view, it get a member function not found error.

Comment: I believe you do not have "given_to", but instead the function itself (as {{ $transactions->givenTo()->name }} )

Comment: You're right @Victor. It worked! When I used $transaction->given_to->givenTransaction(), then that key gets dumped to the screen but not the model. So something like $transaction->given_to->givenTransaction()->name would return null. This line $transactions->givenTo() will return the model, so something like $transactions->givenTo()->name would return the name once the relationship mentioned in your original answer has been set up in the Transaction model.